# PLSQL Decode function where source and target parameters are unknown

Tags: plsql

I have this tricky problem that I can't find the solution for anywhere.
There is a list of values that keep changing in the existing script and as such there is always a need to ask the developer to change it in the script.
They want me to make it table driven, so the operator will update the table with the source and the target values and the script will take the values from the table. There is no set number of pairs, the list can grow or shrink.
Here is the code as it is now (the values are masked for security reasons):

> ```
> DECLARE
> string_v VARCHAR2(200);
> CURSOR dba_synonyms_c IS  
>     SELECT synonym_name, DECODE(table_owner || '.', '.',NULL, table_owner || '.') || table_name || '@' || DECODE(db_link,
>                   'ABC.URL.CA',   'BCF.URL.CA',
>                   'CCD.URL.CA',   'DBS.URL.CA', 
>                   'FEQ.URL.CA',   'HIJ.URL.CA',
>                   'SPO.URL.CA',   'KLM.URL.CA',
>                   'ADT.URL.CA',   'TKJ.URL.CA',
>                   'LMD.URL.CA',   'QSP.URL.CAA',
>                   db_link) AS remote_object
>     FROM dba_synonyms
>     WHERE db_link IS NOT NULL
>     AND synonym_name NOT IN ('SOMENAME'); 
>
> BEGIN    
>    FOR dba_synonyms_r IN dba_synonyms_c LOOP
>        string_v := 'CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM ' || 
>        dba_synonyms_r.synonym_name || ' FOR ' ||
>        dba_synonyms_r.remote_object;
>
>        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (string_v);    
>    END LOOP;
> END;
> /
> ```

The problem is that the source and target values are not fixed and so I can't apply a regular decode function when you know the source upfront and take the target value based on it from the table. I need to get both, the source and the target, from the table and apply them into Decode (or any other appropriate solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can totally do this.
The thing is, you have to join with the mapping table on the key.

```
DECLARE
  string_v VARCHAR2(200);
  CURSOR dba_synonyms_c IS 
    with mapping_table as (
        select 'ABC.URL.CA' as k, 'BCF.URL.CA' as v from dual union all
        select 'CCD.URL.CA' as k, 'DBS.URL.CA' as v from dual union all
        select 'FEQ.URL.CA' as k, 'HIJ.URL.CA' as v from dual
      ),
      dba_synonyms as (
        select 'FIRST_TABLE_OWNER'  as table_owner , 'FIRST_TABLE'  as table_name, 'CCD.URL.CA' as db_link,          'SYN_1' as synonym_name from dual union all
        select null                 as table_owner , 'SECOND_TABLE' as table_name, 'ABC.URL.CA' as db_link,          'SYN_2' as synonym_name from dual union all
        select 'SECOND_TABLE_OWNER' as table_owner , 'THIRD_TABLE'  as table_name, 'NON_EXISTING_KEY' as db_link,    'SYN_3' as synonym_name from dual
      )
      SELECT ds.synonym_name, 
             DECODE(ds.table_owner || '.', 
                    '.', NULL,
                    ds.table_owner || '.'
                   ) || 
                   ds.table_name || '@' || 
                   DECODE(ds.db_link,
                          mt.k, mt.v,
                          ds.db_link
                         ) AS remote_object
      FROM dba_synonyms ds
      LEFT JOIN mapping_table mt on (mt.k = ds.db_link)
      ;

BEGIN    
  FOR dba_synonyms_r IN dba_synonyms_c 
  LOOP
    string_v := 'CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM ' || 
                   dba_synonyms_r.synonym_name || ' FOR ' ||
                   dba_synonyms_r.remote_object;
     dbms_output.put_line(string_v);
     END LOOP;
END;
```

The with clause is here just to simulate tables.

You can remove 'dba_synonyms', and the cursor will use your real dba_synonyms table there.

You can also remove 'with mapping_table', and instead in join put your mapping_table.

That way you map 'k' column from mapping_table to the 'v' column.
And the 'k' is always your value from dba_synonyms.

PS: aks your DBAs what they think about dynamically creating synonyms that way.
It seems that you really want to do something very, very bad.

Also the code obviously only makes sense when values in 'key' column are unique.
Otherwise you will get multiple rows for one synonym.

Comment: regarding "aks your DBAs what they think about dynamically creating synonyms that way" : this is what the script does today. I am not going to change the idea, just update the logic to be table driven. Thanks a lot for your help - much appreciated.

Comment: @SlavaS.

I did not realize until now that there is even simpler solution.
Just skip the decode altogether, and instead use:
nvl(mt.v, ds.db_link).

Comment: Nice! Just tested it, works like charm.
Thanks a lot!